# JDBC connected to wrong server

Tags: sql-server, jdbc

I have access to several SQL Servers in domain.
In SSMS whan I run query `SELECT serverproperty('InstanceDefaultDataPath') as dataFolder;` (on SQL Server 2019 named **MSSQL\SQL20119**) it returns the folder as expected:

D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.**SQL2019**\MSSQL\DATA\

Whan I run the same query using JDBC, it returns data folder of different SQL Server.

```
public static String getSqlServerDataFolder(Connection connection) {
    String query = "SELECT serverproperty('InstanceDefaultDataPath') as dataFolder;";
    List<String> results = getSqlResults(connection, query, "dataFolder");
    return results.get(0);
}

public static List<String> getSqlResults(Connection connection, String query, String key) {
    List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        statement.setQueryTimeout(60);
        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery(query);
        while (result.next()) {
            results.add(result.getString(key));
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return results;
}

public static Connection connectSql(String dataSource) {
    String connectionString = null;
    if (networkSqlServerNames.contains(dataSource)) {
        connectionString = "jdbc:sqlserver://" + dataSource + ":1433;integratedSecurity=true";
    }
    else {
        connectionString = "jdbc:sqlserver://" + dataSource + ";integratedSecurity=true";
    }
    Connection connection = null;
    try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return connection;
}
```

An example:

```
    Connection connection = SqlExpressManager.connectSql("MSSQL\\SQL2019");
    System.out.println(SqlExpressManager.getServerName(connection));
    System.out.println(SqlExpressBackupManager.getSqlServerDataFolder(connection));
    System.out.println(SqlExpressBackupManager.getSqlServerBackupFolder(connection));
```

output:

MSSQL\SQL2019

d:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.**SQL2016**\MSSQL\DATA
d:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.**SQL2016**\MSSQL\Backup

Why are those result different? What to do to make the JDBC returning right values?

Another symptom is with creating database using JDBC:

1. connecting to server A
2. execute query to create database
3. database is created on server B

**Final update:**

Many thanks to Mark Rotteveel and Dan Guzman. This moved me forward:

> the instance name is ignored when a port number is specified so you
> are running against the default instance instead of the named instance
> as intended.

One of four SQL Servers had indeed default TCPIP port 1433. Other had dynamic TCPIP ports. Now every SQL Server has dedicated it's own TCPIP port and I'm adding the port number from a static `Map<String, String>`.

```
public static Connection connectSql(String dataSource) {
    String connectionString = null;
    if (networkSqlServerNames.contains(dataSource)) {
        connectionString = "jdbc:sqlserver://" + dataSource + ":" + tcpipPortMap().get(dataSource) + ";integratedSecurity=true";
    }
    else {
        connectionString = "jdbc:sqlserver://" + dataSource + ";integratedSecurity=true";
    }
    Connection connection = null;
    try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return connection;
}
```

Comment: If you were connected to the *correct* instance the database would be created on the correct instance. You can't use the `CREATE DATABASE` syntax to create a database on a different instance.

Comment: I simply connect to server A, perform `CREATE DATABASE 'FOO'` and it's created on server B.

Comment: You probably need to set some break points in your code. Somewhere along the line it is connecting to server B.

Comment: Already did and it's not.

Comment: `System.out.println(SqlExpressManager.getServerName(connection));` prints correct value. It's connected to the right server. But still next queries are returning different values than I see in SSMS.

Comment: Then you *aren't* connected to the same instance; it's as simple as that. You might *think* you are, but the fact that your statements are returning information from the other instance, and performing DDL statements against the other instance is evidence to the contrary.

Comment: What's in the `networkSqlServerNames` collection (I assume)? Could it be causing it to try to connect to `MSSQL\SQL2019:1433` when `MSSQL\SQL2019` isn't even listening on port 1433?

Comment: It's `List<String>` containg currently only `MSSQL\SQL2019`.

Comment: You raise a good point there, @AlwaysLearning. The default port for SQL Server is 1433, so having 2 different connection, one that specifies 1433 and the other than doesn't does seem odd. You would expect the one that defines a port to define a non-default port number. You can't have 2 instances, on the same host, running on the same port.

Comment: Make sure the SQL Server Browser service is running and specify either `jdbc:sqlserver:hostname\SQL2019`, or `jdbc:sqlserver:hostname:port` with the right port of your instance.

Comment: Adding to the comment by @MarkRotteveel, the instance name is ignored when a port number is specified so you are running against the default instance instead of the named instance as intended.